# Build app using free provisioning

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ipa

Is it possible to launch a build created using free provisioning profile on other device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, the limitations are the following:

> Apple has imposed a number of limitations on when and how you can use
>   free provisioning to run your application on an iOS device, ensuring
>   that you can only deploy to your device. These are listed in this
>   section.
>
> Access to iTunes Connect is also limited and therefore services such
>   as publishing to the App Store and TestFlight are unavailable to
>   developers provisioning their applications freely. An Apple Developer
>   Account (Enterprise or Personal) is required to distribute via Ad Hoc
>   and In-House means.
>
> Provisioning Profiles created in this way will expire after one week,
>   Signing Identities after one year. Furthermore, provisioning profiles
>   will only be created with explicit App IDs and so you will need to
>   follow the instructions above for every app that you wish to install.
>
> Provisioning for most application services is also not possible with
>   free provisioning. This includes:

- List item
- Apple Pay
- Game Center
- iCloud
- In-App Purchasing
- Push Notifications
- Wallet (Was Passbook)

Comment: Can I create .ipa file and send it to other user who doesn't have Xcode, just device? Will this work?

Comment: Yes, I don´t think it´s a limitation for that but the provisioning profile will expire after one week (as stated above).